# How to execute an unordered SQL script

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a SQL script but there is an issue with the order of the statements in the script

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE (ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO permissions (id, name) VALUES (8, 'update');
```

The order of occurrence in the script should have been reverse! And this results in a error because the foreign key with id 8 is not yet inserted when the first statement executes

leading to:

```
[Code: -177, SQL State: 23503]  integrity constraint violation: 
foreign key no parent; PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE_PERM_FK table: PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE value: 8
```

statements used to create the relationships are as below

```
create table PERMISSIONS ( ID bigint not null, NAME varchar(255), primary key (ID) );

create table PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE ( ROLE_ID bigint not null, PERMISSION_ID bigint not null, primary key (ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID) );

alter table PERMISSIONS_FOR_ROLE add constraint permissions_for_role_perm_fk foreign key (PERMISSION_ID) references PERMISSIONS;
```

Any suggestions on how to execute such a script ? I tried manually changing the order and the script executes properly but is there any other way to do it as its run as part of a ANT build target.

Comment: If you really can't control the generation of the INSERT statements, then you could just not apply the foreign key constraint (ie. don't run the "alter table" statement) until AFTER you've done all of the inserts ..... that's assuming that you're confident that everything that gets inserted will honour the constraint (otherwise, you'll get an error trying to apply for foreign key constraint if there are records that violate it)

Comment: Thanks for that advice. There are no records that violate the keys, they are just not in order.

Comment: In that case you should be fine to just do the inserts first (in whatever order they end up in the script) and then apply the foreign key constraint.  Is it ideal?  Probably not - but sometimes we've just gotta do things because we have to (particularly when there are other factors that we can't necessarily control)

Answer (score 0):

For mass inserts with very large scripts that are out of order, you can disable referential integrity checks with:

```
SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE
```

see http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_sql_settings on how to check for possible violations after the insert.